# Making ssh connection permanent

Tags: networking, server, ssh

On the server `user@192.168.0.1`, I've an application running at `http://localhost:8888`

And usually on the client, I'll have to do this to connect to the server application:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 user@192.168.0.1
```

But this connect gets killed once the client turns off and it needs to be reconnected using the same ssh command.

**Is there a way on the client to keep the ssh connection alive on the port regardless of whether the client is shut off or even if the server is down?**

Comment: Do you mean that you want a connection that *automatically reconnects* when the client resumes? Or do you mean that you want *jobs to keep running* on that server after disconnection?

Comment: Both I guess. Just in case the client dies while the job is running.

Comment: Look up how to use a Terminal Multiplexer. There are several good ones in the Ubuntu Repositories - `screen` and `tmux`. Look them up. Install them on the server. Use them to run the job on the server.

Comment: How about on the client? Most of the time, it's the client that gets killed and the ssh needs to be re-done on the client =(

Comment: Aha, found the duplicate of the entire question: https://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session